# Мне нужно заполнить словарь значениями за некоторых условий

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари, список

Мне нужно заполнить словарь значениями за некоторых условий
У меня есть словарь default

```
default = {
    'age': 21,
    'last_name': 'George',
    'birth_day': '1992.01.01',
    'balance': '1000'

}
```

в котором нужно изменить значениям за некоторых условий:

- ключи со значение типа int должны иметь среднее значение всех значений из другого списка словарей
- ключи со значением типа string должны иметь значение которое встречается чаще всего в другом списке словарей с таким же ключом
- для других типов данных заполнять None или же Null

Вот список словарей из которого должны втягиваться значения для заполнения

> {'name': 'Hazel', 'time_created': datetime.date(2022, 10, 4), 'gender': 'female', 'last_name': 'Bowen', 'age': 60, 'birth_day': '1992.01.01', 'balance': '1000'}, {'name': 'Kyla', 'time_created': datetime.date(2022, 10, 4), 'age': None, 'last_name': 'George', 'birth_day': '1992.01.01', 'balance': '1000'}, {'name': 'Timothy', 'time_created': datetime.date(2022, 10, 4), 'gender': None, 'last_name': 'Mcconnell', 'age': 24, 'city': None, 'birth_day': '1992.01.01', 'balance': '1000'}, {'name': 'Raymond', 'time_created': datetime.date(2022, 10, 4), 'gender': 'male', 'last_name': 'Lim', 'birth_day': '24.02', 'age': 21, 'balance': '1000'}, {'name': 'Ellis', 'time_created': datetime.date(2022, 10, 4), 'gender': 'female', 'city': 'Sumy', 'age': 21, 'last_name': 'George', 'birth_day': '1992.01.01', 'balance': '1000'} и так далее...

вот код программы в целом

```
import jsonlines
import datetime
import itertools

with jsonlines.open('data.jsonl', 'r') as jsonl_f:
    lst = list(jsonl_f)

# сортируем список
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x['time_created'], reverse=False)

unique_list = []
temp = ''
# удаляем дубликаты из списка словарей
for my_dict in lst:
    if temp != my_dict['name']:
        if temp != my_dict['time_created']:
            unique_list.append(my_dict)
            temp = my_dict['name']

# переводим время в тип date.time
for value in lst:
    value['time_created'] = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(value['time_created'])

# создаем список уникальных ключей
res = list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(sub.keys() for sub in lst)))


#словарь обычных значений
default = {
    'age': 21,
    'last_name': 'George',
    'birth_day': '1992.01.01',
    'balance': '1000'

}

# добавляем отсутствующие ключи в список словарей
for value in unique_list:
    for key, val in default.items():
        value[key] = value.get(key, val)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот такой функционал нужен? (не очень понятно по описанию)

```
objects = [{'value': 32, 'text': 'xxx'}, {'value': 11, 'text': 'yyy'}, {'value': 100, 'text': 'xxx'}, {'value': 32, 'text': 'xxx'}, {'value': 25, 'text': 'yyy'}]

# собрать все значения по ключам
total = dict()
for obj in objects:
    for key, value in obj.items():
        total[key] = total.get(key, []) + [value]

# обработать значения
for key, value in total.items():
    if type(total[key][0]) == int:
        total[key] = sum(total[key]) / len(total[key])
    elif type(total[key][0]) == str:
        import collections
        freq = collections.Counter(total[key])
        total[key] = max(freq.items(), key=lambda elem: elem[1])[0]
    else:
        total[key] = None

print(total)
```

Comment: появляется данная ошибка total[key] = sum(total[key]) / len(total[key])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: проверьте - значит или значение по ключу было не целым числом (хотя ожидается, что все значения по данному ключу будут целыми). Я данным примером показал подход, оберните в try except и верните содержимое списка когда исключение возникнет, тогда будет понятно что там за проблема